# Biggest Value of $\Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

Given $\Pr(A) = 0.7$ and $\Pr(B) = 0.9$, what is the highest possible value of $\Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram.  Done.  You can find this approach explained and illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466434.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Pr(A\cup B) \in [0,1] $. So if we assume that $\Pr(A\cup B) =1$, then we would have $\Pr (A\cap B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A\cup B) = 0.7 + 0.9 - 1 = 0.6$. Hence the biggest value $\Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$ will be $\Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B) = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4$

Comment: That is the highest possible value but not a proof.  Perhaps say $\Pr(A \cup B)=\Pr(A ) +\Pr(B ) - \Pr(A \cap B)$ so $\Pr(A \cup B) - \Pr(A \cap B)=2\Pr(A \cup B) -\Pr(A ) -\Pr(B )$ which is maximised here when $\Pr(A \cup B)$ is maximised.  And $\Pr(A \cup B)=1$ is the highest possible value here

Comment: @Henry +1 but note that the question does not ask for a proof, only for the highest possible value.